# Disable callout (context menu) on Android

Tags: android, html, css, web-applications, touch

In a web app, I need to disable the default callout that mobile browsers shows when touching and holding ("long tap") on a touch target, such as an `<img>` or a link.

I am already using `-webkit-touch-callout: none;` which works fine on iPhone and iPad, but doesn't seem to work on Android (tested on Android 4.4).

[This post](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-pointer-events/2014AprJun/0102.html) from the W3 mailing list suggests adding a listener for the "contextmenu" event in Javascript and calling `e.preventDefault()`. This does not seem to work either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

You can try to do this :

```
window.oncontextmenu = function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     event.stopPropagation();
     return false;
};
```

I hope this is useful...

[Doc oncontextmenu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oncontextmenu)

Comment: As stated in my question, I tried this already and it does not work.

Comment: You have not talk about the stopPropagation.

Comment: What difference does it make in this context? I'm trying to prevent the default browser action, not to prevent the event from bubbling up..

Comment: I have try on Android 4.4.2 and it's working. Did you tried this piece of code ?
[Snippet on CodePen](https://codepen.io/Zagonine/pen/NxRbvJ)

Comment: this solution worked for me, the css only one did not

Answer (score 0):

```js
   

 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <script>
        function absorbEvent_(event) {
          var e = event || window.event;
          e.preventDefault && e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation && e.stopPropagation();
          e.cancelBubble = true;
          e.returnValue = false;
          return false;
        }
    
        function preventLongPressMenu(node) {
          node.ontouchstart = absorbEvent_;
          node.ontouchmove = absorbEvent_;
          node.ontouchend = absorbEvent_;
          node.ontouchcancel = absorbEvent_;
        }
    
        function init() {
          preventLongPressMenu(document.getElementById('doodle'));
        }
      </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init()">
      <img id="doodle" src="http://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2015/spain-elections-2015-5652792221892608-hp2x.jpg" width="400">
    </body>
    </html>
```

It should be work on 1.6 ("Donut") or above. hope it will help.

Comment: This disables all events. I need to disable context menus on touch targets but these should still be touchable.

Answer (score 0):

This pure CSS approach works for me:

```
    pointer-events: none; // for Android
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; // for iOS
    -webkit-user-select: none; 
    -khtml-user-select: none; 
    -moz-user-select: none; 
    -ms-user-select: none; 
    user-select: none;
```

Comment: `pointer-events: none` disables all pointer events. I needed to disable only context menus; all other touch events should not be disabled.

Comment: @Grodriguez Have you find the solution?

Comment: @captaindroid Nope